# Save column value based on the item in combobox

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps

in PowerApps, I have default New Form screen for Table1 with Combobox linked to Table2 so the user is able to choose items from the Table2. Combobox is saving the selected item Column1 data from Table2 to Column1 in Table1.

What I need, is to be able to save appropriate combobox item Column2 data (from Table2) to Column 2 in Table 1.

Basically, I need to save item's Column1 AND! Column2 data from Table2 to Column1 and Column2 of Table1.

BTW: Tables are lists on Sharepoint.

Can you help please?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This level of customisation requires in any case abandoning the out-of-the-box forms and creating your own.  For a simple example of this, [please see here](https://baizini-it.com/blog/index.php/2017/09/28/powerapps-101-create-your-own-forms/).

The approach to store the individual selected values in separate columns in Table 1 (as you suggest) is not the approach I would recommend.  This is relatively easy to implement but is incomplete and has shortcomings, including but not limited to:

- You need to create as many columns as there may be items in Table 2, and the number of items in Table 2 may vary over time
- PowerApps cannot currently set a column value to Blank() in a data source, so you will need a work-around to deal with the situation where an item previously selected needs to be unselected

The correct way to deal with the combo box is to create a many-to-many relationship as outlined in [this post](https://baizini-it.com/blog/index.php/2017/10/10/powerapps-101-many-to-many-relationships-between-tables/).

When saving the changes, you need to:

1. Remove any records in the junction table where an item has been unselected via a Remove or RemoveIf statement
2. Create an entry for each new item that has been added to the relationship via a Collect or a Patch function

If you need guidance on this, please comment this answer and I will add more details.